# Чтение таблиц из pdf java

Tags: java, pdf, io

Мне нужно прочитать [вот этот документ](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18KXTL5mNm-NfpUbch3fg0hLcA-J7bvub/view). Пытался сделать это с помощью pdfbox:

```
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File(path));
    PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
    String text = stripper.getText(document);
```

Но текст не возвращается. Каким еще способом я могу сделать это?

Answer (score 0):

С точки зрения использования pdfbox вы все делаете правильно. Проблема в том, что в Вашем документе нет текста. Это сканированные картинки , помещенные в pdf. pdfbox не распознает текст из картинки, поэтому в переменную text не попадает ничего, кроме пробелов и переноса строки. аналогичный эффект вы можете получить, если вставите картинку с текстом в документ doc и попытаетесь ее редактировать. в том , что ваш код работает вы также можете легко убедиться, подставив на вход другой pdf- документ

Comment: А есть способы извлечь из pdf картинку и извлечь из нее текст? Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: картинки получить можно, проблема в другом - вы когда-нибудь пользовались обычным сканером? пытались распознать текст? здесь все непросто. оптическое распознание - задача нетривиальная, но если хотите попробовать, то смотрите в сторону open source ocr библиотек, что-то вроде https://sourceforge.net/projects/javaocr/